# Dart: Error When Subscribing to a Non-Broadcast Mapped Stream

Tags: android, flutter, dart, asynchronous, stream

I have a dummy `Stream<int>` called `intialStream` and I am mapping it into another stream, called `mappedStream`. which is supposed to be a new stream as I quote from the documentation of the `map` method:

> Creates a new stream that converts each element of this stream to a
> new value using the convert function, and emits the result.

```
void main() {
  Stream<int> initialStream = Stream<int>.value(0);//using broadcast stream instead, makes the code work, as if dart considers the mapped stream to be the same stream as this one when I am using non-broadcast streams !
  initialStream.listen(print);
  var mappedStream = initialStream.map((nb) => nb + 1);
  print(initialStream == mappedStream); // prints false !
  mappedStream.listen(print);//error here
}
```

The problem is that when I try to listen to the mapped stream, I get an error:

```
Bad state: Stream has already been listened to.
```

Isn't this supposed to be a new stream and thus I can listen to it separately?

Comment: `initialStream.listen` and `initialiStream.map` both end up adding listeners to `initialStream`, but a non-broadcast `Stream` may have only one listener.  If you really need both, you could combine the callbacks: `var mappedStream = initialStream.map((nb) { print(nb); return nb + 1; });`.

Comment: @jamesdlin I don't get you, `mappedStream` is  a `Stream`, constructed internally as I suppose by something like `StreamController` which, each time `initialStream` emits a value, then it maps that value using the provided converting function and emits that value. Isn't this a standalone non-broadcast stream which I can listen to ?

Comment: It has nothing to do with `mappedStream`.  You are reading from `initialStream` twice, once to print the values, once to map values.  Remove the `initialStream.listen` line and you'll see the error go away.

Comment: @jamesdlin so if I get you right, there is no underlying `StreamController` associated with `mappedStream` which `add`s events to the sink of that stream. pardon me I am still new to streams

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you do create a new stream when you use `map()` method, but the new stream also listens on the original stream. So, you cannot listen on the new stream that is created using the methods (`map()`, `where()`, `expand()`...) after adding a subscription to the original stream which is single-subscription.

It's not explicitly stated in docs, but check out the following lines that you might get a general idea:

#### [Methods that modify a stream](https://dart.dev/tutorials/language/streams#modify-stream-methods)

> The following methods on Stream return a new stream **based on the
> original stream**. Each one waits until someone listens on the new
> stream before **listening on the original**:
>
> ```dart
> Stream<R> cast<R>();
> Stream<S> expand<S>(Iterable<S> Function(T element) convert);
> Stream<S> map<S>(S Function(T event) convert);
> Stream<T> skip(int count);
> Stream<T> skipWhile(bool Function(T element) test);
> Stream<T> take(int count);
> Stream<T> takeWhile(bool Function(T element) test);
> Stream<T> where(bool Function(T event) test);
> ```

Here, you can say that the new stream will listen on the original one once a subscription is added. Therefore, it will throw error if the original stream is single-subscription and it already has a listener.

Comment: so the devil was in the detail:  "based on the original stream"

Comment: just one more thing, in this case I understand that I don't have to close any stream controllers that are related to `mappedStream` since there isn't any new controller created for it, it already listens to the `initialStream`'s controller, right?

Comment: Yes. There is no other stream controller other than the one for the original stream.

Comment: so I don't need to do any cleanup on the returned stream from the `map` true?

Comment: Yep. Since the new stream is based on the source stream, it will be closed when you close the source stream. However, you may want to cancel the subscription(s) added to the new stream when you're done listening to it: Get the subscription`final subscription = mappedStream.listen(print);` and then call `subscription.cancel();` to cancel.